# Diamond Square Algorithm in VBA (to run in excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a script in VBA to create random terrain generation in excel, based on this following matlab script (http://knight.temple.edu/~lakamper/courses/cis350_2004/sources/matlabFractal/createFractalTerrain.m)

After compiling my script I found no bugs, but upon running in excel only cell A1 is assigned a value of zero, and then the script ends.

Now, I wondered if anyone had the time to look through my VBA script and see if they have any idea what's going wrong. I think maybe perhaps I mess around with an array called TR quite a bit when I could perhaps refer to the Cells directly from the get go.

Now, the code is bit long so I have provided a link to the text file that here, and so if nobody has the time I completely understand

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c2l2ha0awirlowb/AAARGVpidQGP7I9Yu0XRN8yaa?dl=0

Also, here is the code indented.

```
Public TR(1 To 129, 1 To 129) As Double

Sub DiamondSquare()
    Dim tsize As Long: tsize = 129
    Dim StartRangRange As Double: startRandRange = 64.5
    Dim H As Double:     H = 0.9
    Call createFractalTerrain(tsize, startRandRange, H)
End Sub


Function createFractalTerrain(ByVal tsize As Long, ByVal startRandRange As Double, ByVal H As Double) As Variant
'Function creates fractal terrain by midpoint displacement (diamond square algorithm)
'Output should be a tsize by tsize matrix
'tSize must be a (power of 2) + 1 ie 129
'startRandRange defines the overall elevation; size/2 gives natural images
'Roughness H (between 0 and 1); 0.9 is a natural value
'H=0 is max roughness

    'Initiate Terrain
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim ii As Long
    Dim jj As Long

    For i = 1 To tsize
        For j = 1 To tsize
            TR(i, j) = 10000
        Next
    Next

    TR(1, 1) = 0
    TR(1, tsize) = 0
    TR(tsize, 1) = 0
    TR(tsize, tsize) = 0

    tsize = tsize - 1
    randRange = startRandRange

    'Main Loop
    While tsize > 1
        Call diamondStep(tsize, randRange)
        Call squareStep(tsize, randRange)

        tsize = tsize / 2
        randRange = randRange * (1 / (2 ^ H))
    Wend

    For ii = 1 To tsize
        For jj = 1 To tsize
            Cells(ii, jj).Value = TR(ii, jj)
        Next
    Next

End Function


Sub diamondStep(ByVal tsize As Integer, ByVal randRange As Double)

    sh = tsize / 2
    maxIndex = UBound(TR, 1)

    RowVal = 1 + sh
    ColVal = 1 + sh

    While RowVal < maxIndex
        While ColVal < maxIndex

            'Average height value of 4 cornerpoints
            ValueH = TR(RowVal - sh, ColVal - sh) + TR(RowVal - sh, ColVal + sh) + TR(RowVal + sh, ColVal - sh) + TR(RowVal + sh, ColVal + sh)
            ValueH = ValueH / 4

            'Displacement
            displacement = Int((1 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0) * randRange - randRange / 2
            ValueH = ValueH + displacement

            'Set diamond point
            If TR(RowVal, ColVal) = 10000 Then TR(RowVal, ColVal) = ValueH

            'Next square in same row
            ColVal = ColVal + tsize
        Wend

        'Next row
        ColVal = 1 + sh
        RowVal = RowVal + tsize
    Wend

End Sub


Sub squareStep(ByVal tsize As Integer, ByVal randRange As Double)

    sh = tsize / 2
    maxIndex = UBound(TR, 1)
    colStart = 1 + sh
    RowVal = 1
    ColVal = colStart

    While (RowVal <= maxIndex)
        While (ColVal <= maxIndex)
            ValueH = 0
            nop = 4     'number of points

            'the following cases handle the boundary points,
            'i.e. the incomplete diamonds

            'north
            If RowVal > 1 Then
                ValueH = ValueH + TR(RowVal - sh, ColVal)
            Else
                nop = nop - 1
            End If

            'east
            If ColVal < maxIndex Then
                ValueH = ValueH + TR(RowVal, ColVal + sh)
            Else
                nop = nop - 1
            End If

            'south
            If RowVal < maxIndex Then
                ValueH = ValueH + TR(RowVal + sh, ColVal)
            Else
                nop = nop - 1
            End If

            'west
            If ColVal > 1 Then
                ValueH = ValueH + TR(RowVal, ColVal - sh)
            Else
                nop = nop - 1
            End If

            'displacement
            displacement = Int((1 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0) * randRange - randRange / 2
            ValueH = ValueH / nop + displacement

            'set square point (if not predefined)
            If TR(RowVal, ColVal) = 10000 Then TR(RowVal, ColVal) = ValueH

            'next diamond in same row
            ColVal = ColVal + sh
        Wend

        'next row
        'the starting column alternates between 1 and sh
        If colStart = 1 Then
            colStart = sh + 1
        Else
            colStart = 1
        End If

        ColVal = colStart
        RowVal = RowVal + sh
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Please update your question with a MCVE - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. As it is, your question will be closed as off-topic. You should also debug your script and describe what fails and where and what help you need.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/802/introduction-to-vba/15512/debugging) might also be of help

Comment: I strongly recommend you install and use Smart Indenter to make your code readable. http://www.oaltd.co.uk/indenter/

Comment: I will install the indenter and readdress the text file

Comment: Debuggin also currently yields no issues

Comment: What's the value of tSize when you output to the sheet?  Seems like just before that you've been dividing it by 2....

Comment: I'm hoping tSize begins as an 129 by 129 matrix

Comment: @RThompson Debugging should point out what's wrong with your script. Your code is doing something that you don't expect so it's definitely wrong - your code may execute with no errors but the output is still wrong. Use the debugger to determine the state of your various variables and see which ones have unexpected value. Place breakpoints on important variables and inspect them when the code stops on them.

Comment: I think this is because you are manually setting `TR(1, 1) = 0`. When you reach this `For ii = 1 To tsize` tsize value is 1. So it's only going to do 1 iteration. You are overwriting tsize's value with this: `tsize = tsize / 2`. Maybe you need another variable to hold this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue you are experiencing is from not iterating over the array you created as you are resetting the `tsize` variable to 1.

Changing your code to something like this:

```
For ii = 1 To 129
    For jj = 1 To 129
        Cells(ii, jj).Value = TR(ii, jj)
    Next
Next
```

Produces a grid of 129 Rows and 129 columns with numeric values. Alternatively you could use the `LBound(TR)` and `UBound(TR)` to achieve the same result as manually typing 1 to 129 in each of the `For...Loop`. I played around with this, and used a conditional format to color the cells based on their relative size either black or white. Here is the result, I think this is the type of output you are expecting.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was expecting, replicating terrain. Thanks a lot!